# Was für ein/ welche

Tags: word-usage

I'm practicing the use of "was für ein/ welche". Imade a few sentences and I'd appreciate feedback.

> Welches Buch lesen Sie da gerade? - Den neuen Roman von Herta Müller

I chose welches because its a question that has a definite answer, and it's not about a property.

> Welchen Sänger finden Sie am besten?

Again I chose Welchen because the question has a definite answer, and it's not about a property.

> Was für eine karte soll ich den kaufen? Nimm einfach einen Stehplatz

Here it's seems "logical" that there would be more than one possibility for tickets, and tickets have different properties, therefore I chose was für eine.

> Bei Welchen Film hatten Sie im Kino Richtig Spass? Bei Ice age.

Here I chose welchen because the question has a definitie answer, and it's not about a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Welches Buch lesen Sie da gerade? – Den neuen Roman von Herta Müller.

Correct. But

> Was für ein Buch lesen Sie da gerade? – Einen Roman.

is also correct, as the person asking can specify how to answer by either asking *welcher/welche/welches* or *was für*.

This is the same for all your examples.

---

That aside, corrections:

> Was für eine **K**arte soll ich den**n** kaufen? – Nimm einfach einen Stehplatz.
>
> Bei **w**elche**m** Film hatten Sie im Kino **r**ichtig Spa**ß**? – Bei *Ice **A**ge*.

---

If you want to practice, better use declarative sentences and think about what they mean.

> Sie schrieb, an welchem Tag er kommen sollte.
>
> Sie schrieb, an was für einem Tag er kommen sollte. *(a kind of day)*
>
> Er wusste nicht, welchen Zug er nehmen musste.
>
> Er wusste nicht, was für einen Zug er nehmen musste. *(a kind of train)*

But people are sloppy about the fine difference between these two all the time, so don't get a headache about it.